# Share files between host system and docker container using specific UID

Tags: docker

I'm trying to share files within a Docker guest using the volume sharing.  In order to get the same UID, and therefore interoperability with those files, I would like to create a user in the Docker guest with the same UID as my own user.

In order to test out the idea, I wrote the following simplistic Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage

RUN touch /root/uid-$UID
```

Testing it with `docker build -t=docktest .` and then `docker run docktest ls -al /root` reveals that the file is simply named `uid-`.

Is there a means to share host environment variables with Docker during the guest build process?

Comment: Theres currently an open PR to facilitate build-time environment variables; https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9176. It isn't complete yet and won't be in Docker 1.6, but possibly 1.7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The environment is not shared, you could use -e, --env options to set env variables in container.

I usually use this approach when I want to have the same owner of the mapped volume: I check uid & gid of directory in container and then create a corresponding user. Here my script (setuser.sh) which creates a user for a directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

setuser() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <path>"
    return
  fi
  CURRENT_UID=`id -u`
  DEST_UID=`stat -c "%u" $1`
  if [ $CURRENT_UID = $DEST_UID ]; then
    return
  fi
  DEST_GID=`stat -c "%g" $1`
  if [ -e /home/$DEST_UID ]; then
    return
  fi
  groupadd -g $DEST_GID $DEST_GID
  useradd -u $DEST_UID -g $DEST_GID $DEST_UID
  mkdir -p /home/$DEST_UID
  chown $DEST_UID:$DEST_GID /home/$DEST_UID
}
setuser $1
```

And this is the wrapper script which runs commands as the user, where the directory with permissions is specified either as $USER_DIR or in /etc/user_dir

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$USER_DIR" ]; then
  if [ -e /etc/user_dir ]; then
    export USER_DIR=`head -n 1 /etc/user_dir`
  fi
fi
if [ -n "$USER_DIR" ]; then
  if [ ! -d "$USER_DIR" ]; then
    echo "Please mount $USER_DIR before running this script"
    exit 1
  fi
  . `dirname $BASH_SOURCE`/setuser.sh $USER_DIR
fi
if [ -n "$USER_DIR" ]; then
  cd $USER_DIR
fi
if [ -e /etc/user_script ]; then
  . /etc/user_script
fi
if [ $CURRENT_UID = $DEST_UID ]; then
  "$@"
else
  su $DEST_UID -p -c "$@"
fi
```

P.S. Alleo suggested different approach: to map users and groups files into container and to specify uid and gid. So your container does not depend on built-in users/groups you could use it without additional scripts.

Comment: The idea of doing stat on the shared directory is clever indeed.  I like this.  I had otherwise toyed with the idea of doing "echo $UID >> .uid" on the host and then ADDing that file, but your solution is better for it does not introduce any steps.

Comment: I didn't clue in that the shared volume doesn't exist during the build process.  When exactly is this script being executed?

Comment: uid is unknown during container creation for me - containers created and used on different hosts. so my images just have these scripts and second script used either as entrypoint or as run command. User created when container started via docker run.

Comment: I used your idea in a provisioning step executed by the user.  Thank you for the great suggestion.

Comment: How do I run `setuser.sh` and should I copy the above script inside the docker?

Comment: @user977828 both setuser.sh and wrapper scripts (wrapper script is second script in answer) should be inside docker container. setuser.sh called from wrapper script, and wrapper script could be used as ENTRYPOINT, CMD or docker run parameter.

Comment: why is this solution better than forwarding Unix user/groups? See https://gist.github.com/nitrobin/4d16fbe347c150a422ad for example

Comment: @Alleo, forwarding users/groups could be used only if docker container does not create own users/groups and it require more options in order to use docker container - each solution has own pluses and minuses, I'll add forwarding to and answer, thanks.

Answer (score 27):

While researching a solution to this problem, I have found the following article to be a great resource: https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf

In my scripts, the solution boiled down to the following :

```
docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /hostdirectory:/containerdirectory -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd myimage
```

Of course, `id -u` can be replaced by other means of retrieving a user's gid, such as `stat -c "%u" /somepath`

Comment: Also found [here](https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15) as well as the prompt used by tensorflow docker. the full command for me is `docker run --rm --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -it tensorflow/tensorflow:1.14.0-gpu-py3`

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and will probably never be possible because of the design philosophy of keeping builds independent of machines. [Issue 6822](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6822).

Comment: Right, but I'm referring to build time, so that the user is correctly provisioned.

Comment: @alkalinity the problem is that if another user tries to build from your Dockerfile, they won't have the same environment.

Comment: @AdrianMouat That's a fair point. I elected in the end to make it a provisioning step executed by end users of the new base image.  Consequently the shared part of the guest image has no UID dependencies.

Comment: For development this is exactly what you need to do - ie, we dont want secret credentials in source files, only in the host machine environment.

Answer (score 1):

I slightly modified @ISanych answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user_exists() {
  id -u $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
}

group_exists() {
  id -g $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
}

setuser() {
  if [[ "$#" != 3 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <path> <user> <group>"
    return
  fi
  local dest_uid=$(stat -c "%u" $1)
  local dest_gid=$(stat -c "%g" $1)
  if user_exists $dest_uid; then
    id -nu $dest_uid
    return
  fi
  local dest_user=$2
  local dest_group=$3

  if user_exists $dest_user; then
    userdel $dest_user
  fi

  if group_exists $dest_group; then
    groupdel $dest_user
  fi

  groupadd -g $dest_gid $dest_group
  useradd -u $dest_uid -g $dest_gid -s $DEFAULT_SHELL -d $DEFAULT_HOME -G root $dest_user
  chown -R $dest_uid:$dest_gid $DEFAULT_HOME
  id -nu $dest_user
}

REAL_USER=$(setuser $SRC_DIR $DEFAULT_USER $DEFAULT_GROUP)
```

`setuser` function accepts user and group names that you want to assign to uid and gid of provided directory. Then if user with such uid exists then it simply returns login corresponding to this uid, otherwise it creates user and group and returns login originally passed to function.

So you get the login of user that owns destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an accepted answer it does not work for me. I needed the same uid:gid for all the files mounted (with bind) from the host file system in the docker container. It took me nearly 2 days to figure out why docker can't do this and how I can do this nevertheless. I leave it here if someone faces the same issues:

## host directory mounts in docker and why they do not work (edit: in docker desktop)

Docker volume/mounted binds have a significant downside: They statically change ownership: user(1000) becomes root(0) and www-data(33) becomes nobody(65534). And they do not allow to change ownership in the container. Thus access conflicts are mandatory.

This is known as [user namespacing](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/). It is a security feature to prevent privilege-escalation attacks. It can be disabled for containers via the `--userns=host`. However:

> There is a side effect when using this flag: user remapping will not be enabled for that container but, because the read-only (image) layers are shared between containers, ownership of the containers filesystem will still be remapped.
>
> [direct quote from the docker user manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#disable-namespace-remapping-for-a-container)

### edit 24.03.24

The wrong mapping occurs **on docker desktop only** (at least at docker desktop version  4.13.1 (90346)). If I use the docker daemon only, the mapping is always correct.

## how host directory mounts work (with sshfs)

To circumvent this issue we can use battle proven linux server mounting programms like sshfs.

First we need to access our host machine from the container via ssh. Therefore, an ssh server has to be installed on the host (with passwd or ssh-keys configured) and an ssh client on the container.

Host:

```
apt-get update

apt-get install openssh-server -y
```

Container:

```
apt-get update

apt-get install ssh sshfs -y
```

First we check *in the container* if the ssh connection is working via `ssh user@host.docker.internal`.

If it does we configure *in the container* a sshfs mount.

```
sshfs -o allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/$(whoami)/.ssh/id_rsa user@host.docker.internal:/host/source/path /container/target/path
```

If you do not want to supply your password you can leave the containers public ssh key on the host e.g. via `ssh-copy-id`. Then:

```
sshfs -o allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/$(whoami)/.ssh/id_rsa user@host.docker.internal:/host/source/path /container/target/path
```

The sync is almost instant. And the permission mapping is correct even if you create files from within the container.

**Hint:** We need to run container with the `--privileged` flag.

## security aspects (warning)

Since we have to run the container in the privileged mode, `root` in the container is the same as `root` on the host. The same applies for every other user.

Thus, for everything we run in that container we have to put up the same security measures as it would run directly on the host.

We have to run an ssh-server on the host, which has (of course) to be targeted by security measures.

Best practice: Use mounting of host directories for development only.