# Use docker-compose env variable in Dockerbuild file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Having the following docker-compose file:

```
db:
    build: .
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
        - ENV=test
    env_file: .env
```

Is there any way to use the env variables declared in docker-compose.yml (either as environment or declared in the env_file) as part of Dockerfile without declaring them in the Dockerfile? Something like this:

```
FROM java:7
ADD ${ENV}/data.xml /data/
CMD ["run.sh"]
```

Comment: that would be really useful.

Comment: No, this is not possible. It would be very similar to this question on using environment variables from the host: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925006/using-host-environment-variables-with-dockerfile

Comment: Actually, there's work in progress to facilitate this; https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9176 this won't be part of Docker 1.6, but possibly 1.7

Comment: Anyone got answer for this please?? it's 1.8.2 already. I need to get something from docker-compose in Dockerfile!

Comment: As of Docker 1.9, [build-time arguments are now available](https://blog.docker.com/2015/11/docker-1-9-production-ready-swarm-multi-host-networking/). However, Compose [does not support it yet](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2111).

Comment: see how I solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933083/dockerfile-pass-environments-on-docker-compose-build?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 71):

Although this question was asked long ago, there is an answer to a similar question here: [Pass environment variables from docker-compose to container at build stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747843/pass-environment-variables-from-docker-compose-to-container-at-build-stage/41792420#41792420)

Basically, to use variables at the container's build time one has to define the variable in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
build:
  context: .
  args:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ENV: test
```

and then reference it in the `Dockerfile` using `ARG`:

```
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
ARG ENV
ADD ${ENV}/data.xml /data/
```

Concerning environment variables defined in an `*.env` file, I believe that they can't be passed to the container at build time.

Comment: Can these `args` be defined in `env_file: .env` instead of docker-compose and be recognized in Dockefile in a similar way to the mentioned above?

Comment: @JavaSa Googd question as it didn't work in my case in contrary to the official documentation.

Comment: Refer to the linked answer for detailed description. In short, the *.env* file should be used only for variables that the yaml parser needs, and other variables that you want to use in your *Dockerfile* file should be kept in a different file, e.g. *.env.staging* or set up in the `args:` section of your *docker-compose.yml* file - and also explicitly declared in your *Dockerfile* file before use.

Comment: From a security standpoint, this is quite a different answer than was asked. You are embedding potentially sensitive values in a Dockerfile rather than passing them in at run time

Answer (score 51):

It works ok this way:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    container:
        build:
            context: .
            args:
                ENV: ${ENV} # from .env file
        env_file:
            - .env
```

Dockerfile

```
# from compose args
ARG ENV 
ADD ${ENV}/data.xml /data/
```

.env

```
ENV=myenv
```

Thus all the values are taken from .env file

Comment: if is it not exist in .env, how we do set default variable? Is it possible?

Comment: You can do it like this in docker-compose.yml: `ENV: ${ENV:-default_value}`

Comment: `env_file:` has nothing to do here. What it does is take environment variables from the file and inject them into the container, not into build nor docker-compose.yml. Docker compose will, by default, try to load ./.env. If you want it to load a different file, you will have to define it in your docker-compose CMD `docker-compose --env-file my.env up`

Comment: this is not working for me

Answer (score 19):

This approach goes against the 'build once, run anywhere' theory behind Docker and most DevOps approaches. With this approach you'll need to build a container for every environment you expect to use. By doing so you can't safely say if a container works in the dev environment it will work in staging and production since you aren't using the same container.

You'd be better off adding all config files you need on to the container and writing an [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) script that selects/copies the data for that environment to the correct location when the container starts. You can also apply this approach to other config on the container, like templated Apache config using jinja2 templates etc.

Comment: If what you warn was a bad thing, possibly Docker would never have allowed the use of ARG and ENV in the build phase of a container, since changing their values has the potential to generate different images. Technology should work for you, not you for it, so occasionally it is acceptable to break conventions (if you know the implications, especially if they are security related).

Comment: I am using it for react in a multi build env and there's no other way. React uses the environment variables during build phase and then just uses nginx to serve those files. If i need different env variables to be used, i HAVE to pass them at build stage.