# Pass environment variables from docker-compose to container at build stage

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create configuration for several environments with a single `Dockerfile`, several `docker-compose` files and several `envoronment_variables` files. I need it to use a different file with python dependencies for each environment.

Let's say, we create a `web` service in two environments: `development` and `production`. To achieve this, I create the following file structure:

```
docker-compose-dev.yml
docker-compose-prod.yml
envs/
  dev.env
  prod.env
web/
  Dockerfile
  requirements_dev.txt 
  requirements_prod.txt
```

The objective is to instantiate the proper name of a `requirements_*.txt` file in the `Dockerfile` during the container's `build` process. According to the documentation, I tried this naïve approach, which doesn't seem to work:

1. Define the name as an environment variable:

   - **envs/dev.env:** `REQUIREMENTS=requirements_dev.txt`
   - **envs/prod.env:** `REQUIREMENTS=requirements_prod.txt`
2. Use this environment variable in the **Dockerfile**:

   ```
   FROM python:3.5
   ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
   ENV APP_ROOT /usr/src/app
   ...
   COPY $REQUIREMENTS $APP_ROOT/
   RUN pip install -r $APP_ROOT/$REQUIREMENTS
   ```
3. Import the corresponding definition in a `docker-compose` configuration:

   ```
   version: '2'

   services:
       web:
           build: ./web
           env_file:
               - envs/dev.env   # in docker-compose-dev.yml
               - envs/prod.env   # in docker-compose-prod.yml
           ...
   ```

When I run `docker-compose up --build docker-compose-dev.yml`, the `$REQUIREMENTS` variable is not defined at the build process.

In the `docker-compose` [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/envfile) there is a note on this:

> *Note: If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in environment files will not be automatically visible during the build. Use the args sub-option of build to define build-time environment variables.*

But to use the `ARG` option in the `Dockerfile`, like `ARG REQUIREMENTS`, one needs a corresponding `args` option in `docker-compose`, like this:

```
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./web
            args:
                - REQUIREMENTS
```

Nevertheless, with this configuration my tests also failed, because, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/args), the value of the `REQUIREMENTS` variable in Dockerfile is taken from

> *the environment where Compose is running*

Therefore, it takes value from my shell, but not from `envs/dev.env`.

So my question is:

> Is it possible to pass environment variable **from `env_file`** in `docker-compose` **to `Dockerfile` at build time** without setting variables locally in my shell?

Comment: I just ran into this myself. Trying to use `env_file` and also `build: args: FOO: ${SOME_VAR:-foo}` and it seems `SOME_VAR` is not loaded from the `env_file`.. Perhaps this is a bug where `env_file` interpolation happens after or does not apply to build arg resolution?

Comment: I've read in some other question a statement that the Dockerfile is designed to be self-contained, and to not depend on the external environment. But, on the other hand, it contradicts the purpose of `args` and `ARG`. So it's not clear whether it's a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your docker-compose.yml should look like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      args:
        REQUIREMENTS: "requirements_dev.txt"
```

Your Dockerfile should define the build-argument using `ARG` like this:

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV APP_ROOT /usr/src/app
ARG REQUIREMENTS
...
COPY $REQUIREMENTS $APP_ROOT/
RUN pip install -r $APP_ROOT/$REQUIREMENTS
```

I validated this and created a minified functional demo at Github:

https://github.com/jannikweichert/stackoverflow-41747843

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed! Though, one needs to hardcode the variables in the `docker-compose.yml` instead of reading them from an `*.env` file, but this is much better than nothing.

Comment: Great! the good thing is, that as your `Dockerfile` is a specification with explicit information on necessary input variables, your `docker-compose` is an explicit specification of your container setup. No additional files need to be checked by a developer to see what's going on