# Docker-compose variable is not passed into a production vue app

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, docker-compose

Docker-compose environment variables don't seem to be set at all. I have tried using env_file and environment fields but when printing process.env in my vue app the only visible variables are NODE_ENV and BASE_URL

Here is my docker-compose code:

```
    frontend:
    container_name: "Frontend"
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
    env_file:
        - ./frontend.env
    environment: 
        VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL: "django"
    ports: 
        - 8000:80
    command: echo $VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL
```

Frontend Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./front/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./front .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My frontend.env code (This was added as I was trying to debug the problem):

```
VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL=django
VUE_APP_BACKEND_PORT=9000
```

Here is my js code

```
export function getEnvironmentVar(key,defaultVal){
  window.console.log(process.env)
  window.console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL)
  var result = process.env[`VUE_APP_${key}`];
  window.console.log(`Trying to read environment variable: ${key}, got: ${result}`)
  if(result!= undefined)
    return result
  else 
    return defaultVal
}
```

The output:

```
{NODE_ENV: "production", BASE_URL: "/"}
NODE_ENV: "production"
BASE_URL: "/"
__proto__: Object
```

This is the output with the command line in docker-compose added:

```
WARNING: The VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Starting Frontend ... done
Attaching to Frontend
Frontend              | 
Frontend exited with code 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add the docker file ?

Comment: Dockerfile has been added to the question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The environment variables you are setting are applied to the *runtime environment* of the container, and not to the container at build time. Since your web app is built and served statically the environment variables will not be available on the frontend as they were not set when the app was built.

To make the environment variables visible to `vue-cli` when it builds your app, you need to use *build arguments* in your `Dockerfile`. You can then set an environment variable in your build stage with the same value as the build argument, before you run `npm run build`.

**frontend.dockerfile**

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
ARG VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL                       # <-- these two lines have
ENV VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL=$VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL  #      been added
COPY ./front/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./front .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: "Frontend"
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
        args:
          - VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL=django
    ports: 
      - 8000:80
```

Since `VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL` is being set before `npm run build` is executed, the environment variables will be embedded in your built app.

**Sources:**

- StackOverflow - [Pass environment variables from docker-compose to container at build stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41747843/pass-environment-variables-from-docker-compose-to-container-at-build-stage)
- Compose file reference - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build

Comment: hi, i don't really understand the answer. If i build a docker container with url and port given in build envt variables, there is no way to run the container for a different environment (different backend url+port), right ? In this sense, they are not really "environment variables", since we need to rebuild the docker container for any new envt....

Answer (score -5):

You can try the dotenv package

```
npm i dotenv
```

Add to the top of the file

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Comment: Adding dotenv didnt seem to have any effect. The variables are still not there