# Docker creates files as root in mounted volume

Tags: docker, file-ownership, volumes

I'm using Docker (1.3.1) to build RPMs inside a container:

```
docker run -v /home/matt/build:/build build-rpm /build/build-pkg.sh
```

This works fine (my user is in the `docker` group, so I don't need to sudo) and drops a completed `.rpm` file in the current directory. The problem is that the file is created as owned by root.

How can I arrange it so that the file is created owned by the same user as I run docker with?

Comment: "so that the file is created owned by the same user as I run docker with" But this is root inside the docker virtual environment, it doesn't know what your user is.

Comment: see my answer on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925006/using-host-environment-variables-with-dockerfile

Comment: @PaulOliver processes running in the Docker container don't know what my host user is, just as they don't know where on the host I've mounted the volume. However, Docker does let me specify where on the host the volume lives; similarly, can I specify what (host) user new files are created as?

Comment: @ISanych -- nice, your solution is clever and works (wish Docker had a simpler solution, but...)

Answer (score 13):

You could try to create (in the Dockerfile of a custom image)  a user and set it as the one used by the container

```
RUN adduser --system --group --shell /bin/sh auser \
 && mkdir /home/auser/bin
USER auser
```

Then check if a `docker run -v /home/matt/build:/build build-rpm` mounts the shared folder in /build as `auser`.

---

Another option mentioned in [issue 2259](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2259#issuecomment-26564115):

> If you `chown` the volume (on the host side) before bind-mounting it, it will work.
>   In that case, you could do:

```
mkdir /tmp/www
chown 101:101 /tmp/www
docker run -v /tmp/www:/var/www ubuntu stat -c "%U %G" /var/www
```

> (Assuming that `101:101` is the `UID:GID` of the `www-data` user in your container.)

Comment: Pay attention that parent folders (if any) will belong to root. In your example, there is not, but its good to know.

Answer (score 3):

Docker runs as root and has no idea what your user is inside its virtual environment (even if you're in the sudoers group). But you can create a non-root user while building your docker image that can be called whatever you like.

```
# create a non-root user named tester, 
# give them the password "tester" put them in the sudo group
RUN useradd -d /home/tester -m -s /bin/bash tester && echo "tester:tester" | chpasswd && adduser tester sudo

# start working in the "tester" home directory
WORKDIR /home/tester
COPY ./src

# Make the files owned by tester
RUN chown -R tester:tester /home/tester

# Switch to your new user in the docker image
USER tester
```

Comment: I'm not too worried about the container's idea of what user it is inside the container. However, from the host's point of view, I want the file to end up  owned by the user who launched the `docker run` command. Would this approach help with that?

Comment: The file wouldn't be owned by you unless you copied it back to your machine with the same UID and GID. http://superuser.com/questions/580592/does-file-user-ownership-change-when-transferring-files-between-computers

Comment: I guess. I'm used to the simple story manipulate `/vagrant` on a Vagrant VM: the guest's view of the file's owner is different to the host's.