# Warning when trying run tensorflow with Docker on Windows

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I cannot start tensorflow with image download from tensorflow

I used docker on windows 10 and for error ouput said this:

```
WARNING: You are running this container as root, which can cause new files in
mounted volumes to be created as the root user on your host machine.

To avoid this, run the container by specifying your user's userid:

$ docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) args...
```

I try search a problem for google... but cannot found, my experience with docker is null

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning specifying that to access/change the files created in the mounted directory you may require sudo and you may not be able to change such files as a non sudo user, since your docker container used sudo permissions while creating them.

A quick search shows that there are many blog references available, check these -

1. [Docker creates files as root in mounted volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052019/docker-creates-files-as-root-in-mounted-volume)
2. [Running a Docker container as a non-root user](https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15)
3. [Setup Docker for windows using windows subsystem linux](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly)
4. https://jtreminio.com/blog/running-docker-containers-as-current-host-user/
5. https://medium.com/better-programming/running-a-container-with-a-non-root-user-e35830d1f42a
6. https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/