# Why all files created in docker directory write-protected?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-20.04

I have docker set up for a directory using the following command: `sudo docker run --gpus all -it -p 8889:8888 -v <dir-name>:/tf latest-gpu-jupyter`. Jupyter Notebook, drivers for my GPU and Tensorflow comes preinstalled. The problem is that in GUI the files have the following lock:

[image: lock for file icon]

And in terminal, if I use `rm <file-name>`, it returns `rm: remove write-protected regular file '<file-name>'`. I can use `rm -f <file-name>` to avoid this error. But still, is it a normal thing to happen? Can I avoid this in docker?

My environment:

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Docker runs as root user and by default it has no idea about user who is going to use that file. This link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/30052210/8595891

Comment: Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29251160/1811501, in which I proved a more detailed answer about permissions