# the files generated by docker

Tags: docker

My question is the files generated by running docker are not within the user's permission while within the root's. This is absolutely not a feature that I want.

So, there are two possible solutions:
(1) Change the permission after the files are generated. Like, use the command line `chmod 777`. But it is very time-consuming and error-prune.
(2) During the running of the docker directly change the permission of the docker running for which I do not know how to realize but there must be a way to fix it.

Which solution is better? And why?

An example is the following. I create a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.9.0-cuda11.1-cudnn8-devel
```

Then I build it with the command `docker build -t test .`
After that, I run it with the command `docker run -d -t test:latest`.
Then I run `docker exec -it test bash`.
Then I am in the container. Then I run `touch test.txt` and made some editing on the `test.txt`.

Then I exit the container. I would like to edit the `test.txt` on my local machine. Then I find I can not do that.

What should I do? `chmod 777 test.txt` is a solution. But what if I generate multiple files in different locations?

Best regards,

George Yang

Comment: Unfortunately (2) is not possible because the container has its own set of users and doesn't know anything about the users available on the host machine.

Comment: are you using `dockerfile`? this can automate chmod and why do you say 'time-consuming and error-prune'?

Comment: Either have your container run under the UID/GID you want or change the owner of the file inside the container when it's created.

Comment: It is unclear from your question if you mean files created on the host or inside the container. See this perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925006/share-files-between-host-system-and-docker-container-using-specific-uid/51953074#51953074

Comment: If a key part of the application is reading and writing host files as a specific host user, it seems like you might not want Docker's isolated filesystem and ID mappings, and running the program directly on the host could be a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, docker uses the root account when you start the container. But there is nothing stopping you from running as a different user.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user

> USER root (id = 0) is the default user within a container. The image
> developer can create additional users. Those users are accessible by
> name. When passing a numeric ID, the user does not have to exist in
> the container.
>
> The developer can set a default user to run the first process with the
> Dockerfile USER instruction. When starting a container, the operator
> can override the USER instruction by passing the -u option.
>
> -u="", --user="": Sets the username or UID used and optionally the groupname or GID for the specified command.
>
> The followings examples are all valid:
> --user=[ user | user:group | uid | uid:gid | user:gid | uid:group ] Note: if you pass a numeric uid, it must be in the range of
> 0-2147483647.

So, since your user doesn't exist in the image, you can't use your username and must use the uid instead.

Comment: Hi kutschkem, thank you! Your answer solved my long-existing confusion. Thanks again.